# JSON FX results not working for Xcode

Tags: json, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have an application that has extensively used server calls and i used jsonfx to parse the results and when i build the project from unity and run it on my mac it says

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

and application does not processed which is expected because my application depends extensively on responses from the api it hits.
Everything works swiftly on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that Jsonfx is not compatible on ios platform an alternative for that is Newtonsoft.Json

simply put use this :

```
<T>Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString)
```

instead of JsonFx.Json.Reader

```
    JsonFx.Json.JsonReader reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader ();
    <T>reader.Read<T> (jsonString);
```

offcourse you will nedd to add the following files to your code 
[NewtonsoftJson](https://mega.nz/#!6tZy0AiA!I1kzYFc3YUmI1AANVkR_slMnWV_7haYx8yhovoDU2k0)